# Get starting point and ending point of a line in EaselJS

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, easeljs

Is it possible to retrieve these points from a drawn line? The [API](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Graphics.html) didn't really help me.

```
var line = new createjs.Graphics();
line.beginStroke( 'black' );
line.moveTo( 0, 0 );
line.lineTo( 100, 100 );
```

Right now I'm creating an instance of the Point class and use the coordinates as parameters.

```
var point1 = new Point(0, 0);
var point2 = new Point(100, 100);

var line = new createjs.Graphics();
line.beginStroke( 'black' );
line.moveTo( point1.x, point1.y );
line.lineTo( point2.x, point2.y );
```

Comment: Please be more specific on what you are trying to do and what you have tried so far. Are you just trying to find the beginning and end points of a line? Or any point along the line?

Comment: Yes, just the starting point and ending point, nothing more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it would be possible in theory, to retrieve those coordinates, you are far better of saving them as custom objects (Points for example, as you do already).

---

The `Graphics`-object saves those draw-instructions and coordinates in `Commands` (`Command(f, params, path)`) - and all active commands are saved in an array: `line._activeInstructions`

You would have to go through the first and the last command and retrieve the command's `params`-array, those would be your points. But this would only work in your case of a simple line. And since this uses internal variables and methods of the Graphics-object, I highly recommend **not** to do it this way.
Also I'd recommend you to keep the readability of your code in this case instead of trying to save some memory by not using 2 Points with an pretty much unmeasureable memory-effect.

Comment: Thanks, I thought there would be an easy operation for this, like in KineticJS.

Comment: The thing is, that the Graphics-object can be used to draw ANY path/shape, such a generic object cannot anticipate that the shape is just a line (in theory yes, but with an unnecessary overhead), but you could write your own class that inherits from Graphic and implements those point-members that you want.